# Classe retornar chave e valor dos meus atributos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class RegC100:
    def __init__(self,linha):
        def convFloat(valor):
            if (valor != ''):
                valor = float(valor.replace(",", "."))
                return valor
            else:
                return ''

        def convInt(valor):
            if(valor !=''):
                valor = int(valor)
                return valor
            else:
                return ''

        def convData(valor):
            if(valor != ''):
                valorDia = valor[0:2]
                valorMes = valor[2:4]
                valorAno = valor[4:8]
                valor = str(valorAno+'-'+valorMes+'-'+valorDia)
                return valor
            else:
                return ''

        self.linha = linha
        l = linha.split('|')
        self.reg = l[1]
        self.indOper = l[2]
        self.indEmit = l[3]
        self.codPart = l[4]
        self.codMod = l[5]
        self.codSit = l[6]
        self.ser = convInt(l[7])
        self.numDoc = convInt(l[8])
        self.chvNfe = l[9]
        self.dtDoc = convData(l[10])
        self.dtES = l[11]
        self.vlDoc = convFloat(l[12])
        self.indPgto = convInt(l[13])
        self.vlDesc = convFloat(l[14])
        self.vlAbatNt = convFloat(l[15])
        self.vlMerc = convFloat(l[16])
        self.indFrt = l[17]
        self.vlFrt = convFloat(l[18])
        self.vlSeg = convFloat(l[19])
        self.vlOutDa = convFloat(l[20])
        self.vlBcIcms = convFloat(l[21])
        self.vlIcms = convFloat(l[22])
        self.vlBcIcmsSt = convFloat(l[23])
        self.vlIcmsSt = convFloat(l[24])
        self.vlIpi = convFloat(l[25])
        self.vlPis = convFloat(l[26])
        self.vlCofins = convFloat(l[27])
        self.vlPisSt = convFloat(l[28])
        self.vlCofinsSt = convFloat(l[29])
```

que recebe os seguintes dados:

```
|C100|0|1|99900821|55|00|2|000021255|23121207792435000327550020000212551005939150|20122012|20122012|899,00|2|||899,00|0||||0|0||||||||
```

gostaria de fazer essa minha classe retornar os valores dos meus atributos como chave e valor ou pode ser uma opção preparar esses dados pra adicionar no banco de dados sem ter que ficar digitando cada atributo novamente. Existe alguma forma?
Como sou bem novo nesse mundo do python queria também saber se existe alguma coisa onde posso melhorar o código da minha classe.
Desde já agradeço demais a ajuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma maneira prática é adicionar o método `to_dict` à classe:

```
def to_dict(self):
    return self.__dict__
```

Para obter os valores como chave/valor, basta invocar o método: `obj.to_dict()`.

Veja a documentação oficial de `__dict__` [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__).

> Veja o código funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/FStY/0).

Answer (score 5):

Sim - tem várias formas de fazer isso, e as mais sensatas vão trabalhar em conjunto com a sua necessidade de atribuir vários campos a partir de uma linha formatada.

Claro que objetos em Python tem o atributo `__dict__`, como nas outras respostas, que guarda todos os atributos do objeto para você. Usar o `__dict__`diretamente entretanto não é algo muito feito no dia a dia, por que ele não discrimina quem é quem - por exemplo, seu atributo `self.linha` vai star presente no `__dict__` junto com os outros campos.

Um mecanismo bem legal para fazer esse tipo de coisa é  criar uma classe base com um mecanismo de acesso a varios campos pelo nome a partir de uma configuração da própria classe que indique características de cada campo.

Nesse caso, você só precisa do nome do campo, sua posição na linha, e função de conversão. A posição pode ser dada pela ordem que você coloca os campos  - então pode convencionar por exemplo, um atributo de classe `fields`, que seja uma sequência de pares (nome, função de conversão), e colocar um método que popula e outro que recupera todos esses valores.

```
class Base:
    fields = [('reg', str), ('indOper', str), ..., ('vlDoc',convFloat), ...]
    def __init__(self, linha):
          self.linha = linha.split('|')
```

E na verdade, é mais prático se esse "_fields" for um dicionario contendo as informações sobre aquele campo. COmo o Python permite execuçã de código na criação da classe, você pode declarar _fields da forma mais conveniente - por exemplo, como uma única string, e criar o dicionário apropriado com uma função:

converters = 
{'float': convFloat,
 'int': convInt,
 'date': convDate,
 'str': str
}

```
def create_fields(spec):
     from collections import OrderedDict
     fields = OrderedDict()
     for i, field_spec in enumerate(spec.split(',')):
          field_spec = field_spec.strip()  # remove espaços em branco
          field_name, converter_name = field_spec.split()
          # em cada campo guarda sua posição e a função de conversão:
          fields[field_name] = i, converters[converter_name]
```

E agora pode declarar cada classe como:

```
class reg100(Base):
     fields = create_fields("reg str, indOper str, ..., vlDoc float, ...")
```

Também existe o `__getattr__`: é uma função especial que é chamada quando o Python não encontra um atributo num objeto - aí o Python chama esse método passando o nome do atributo. Isso permite que o nome do atributo seja configurado de alguma outra forma que como uma vaiável explictamente setada em código hardcoded.

```
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:       
            field = self.fields[attr]
        except IndexError:
            raise AttributeError
        return field[1](self.linha[field[0]]
```

Com isso, e apenas uma linha por classe derivada (e usandoa  função `__init__` e `__getattr__` declaradas na base),  você define todas as classes do seu projeto. E agora, com essa informaçao no lugar, você pode definir métodos comuns à vontade para  recuperar todos os campos.

Por exemplo, para ter todos os campos convertidos, como uma lista - e mais ainda, com o decorator "property" pode fazer isso parecer um atributo da classe:

```
@property
def field_values(self):
     return [converter(self.linha[position]) for position, converter in self.fields.values()]

@property
def field_dict(self):
    return {attr_name:value[1](self.linha[value[0]) for name, value in self.fields.items()   }
```

Coloque esses 4 métodos na sua classe base, e depois declare suas várias classes como:

```
class Reg100(Base):
    fields = create_fields(""reg str, indOper str, ..., vlDoc float, ...")
```

e vai pode racessar todos os campos:

```
>>> r = Reg100(linha)
>>> r.reg 
(retorna o valor correspontente)
>>> r.field_values
(retorna uma lista com os valores, já convertidos para tipos Python)
```

Lembrando que como seu objetivo é insierrir tudo num banco de dados relacional - você pde usar um ORM como SQLALchmy para facilitar essa parte. O ORM sozinho não vai fazer a atribuição dos valroes da linah a atributos da classe, ou evitar que você fique digitiando uma especificação mais complexa para cada campo - mas você pode combinar o uso do ORM com alugmas dessas dicas.